# CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon

Tags: nagios, nrpe

---

I have configured nagios server on Centos machine. I am trying to add a rhel 6.6 machine to this nagios server Version 4.2.0. While configuring NRPE and testing it, there is a step to check configuration as `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost`

I am getting the error as below at this step:

```
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
```

So, I used the `-n` option: `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -n -H localhost`

And it shows a new error as below:

```
CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon.
```

System logs just say:

```
Aug 31 14:31:10 xxxxx xinetd[18730]: START: nrpe pid=18781 from=::1
Aug 31 14:31:10 xxxxx xinetd[18781]: FAIL: nrpe address from=::1
Aug 31 14:31:10 xxxxx xinetd[18730]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=18781 duration=0(sec)
```

Any idea on why this shows up?

Answer (score 1):

- Check the logs at `/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log` for any errors. This probably is the issue with `nrpe.cfg`, mostly a syntactical error.
- Check your command definitions too in `nrpe.cfg`.
- Also make sure port `5666` is open.
- If you are using nrpe under xinetd, check the allowed hosts entry at `/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe`.

This problem basically arises when nrpe can't read its configurations properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check allowed_hosts parameter in nrpe.cfg file. You need to allow localhost too.

Comment: It is there already.
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
solution : allow hosts in nrpe.conf file
remove -n in the command if ssl is enabled.